# Why does JSON.stringify only include part of this object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, parse-platform, stringify

When I use JSON.stringify on a Parse.com query object, it only includes the "attributes" and ignores the rest. How do I stringify the entire object?

### My query to Parse, logging the results with and without stringify:

```
    // load races from Parse    
    var Events = Parse.Object.extend("Events");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Events);

    query.equalTo("theYear", currentYear);
    query.ascending("sortOrder");       

    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        forgeLog("Got "+results.length+" Events from Parse");

        forgeLog("First object in array logged directly:");
        forgeLog(results[0]);

        forgeLog("First object in array with stringify:");
        forgeLog(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
      },
      error: function(error) {
          forgeLog("Error getting Events from Parse");  
      }
    });
```

### The object logged directly:

```
    { attributes: 
     { Name: 'McCalls Motorworks',
       raceId: '0',
       sortOrder: 2,
       theYear: 2012 },
    _operations: {},
    _dirty: {},
    _hashedJSON: {},
    _escapedAttributes: {},
    cid: 'c0',
    id: 'To6lLjzwQw',
    createdAt: '2012-08-09T13:51:29.259Z',
    updatedAt: '2012-08-10T13:23:07.280Z',
    _setting: false,
    _previousAttributes: 
     { Name: 'McCalls Motorworks',
       raceId: '0',
       sortOrder: 2,
       theYear: 2012 } 
    }
```

### The object logged with stringify:

```
    {"Name":"McCalls Motorworks","raceId":"0","sortOrder":2,"theYear":2012}
```

Update: I actually just tested myself and it works when I manually define the object by cut and pasting the first object and defining the variable myself. However, when I stringify the result directly after receiving it from Parse (as in example code), it only returns the attributes portion...yet the first object is what I copied directly from my console when logging the result from Parse before attempting to stringify.

Comment: On which platform? Works fine for me in Safari 6.0.1

Comment: [Seems fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/9TA34/) too (tested in Chrome 22).

Comment: it should work fine. take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/9TA34/1/.  give more details on browser, js engine.. maybe provide an example

Comment: Please define "entire object". What is missing exactly?

Comment: @LewisDiamond He seemed pretty clear about that: 'includes the "attributes" and ignores the rest.'

Comment: @Barmar "attributes" can refer to properties of the object, to his property called "attributes", or maybe something else. His pasted output is an output? Or is it the input? Does he mean stringify discards the functions? Or something else. This question certainly needs clarifications.

Comment: The above object is the input: it is an object from the response I get from the Parse.com js API when I run a query. When running the stringify directly from the Parse response, it only returns the 'attributes' part of the above object. When I pasted this object directly into my code it is stringified properly. So I guess the real question is: what could be different about the parse object received that is preventing the entire object from being stringified?

Comment: Then give as the real example...

Comment: @DusanRadojevic I've restated the question with a more complete example

Comment: @Barmar I've done my best and updated the question to be more clear. Thanks for you time!

Comment: Change forgeLog to console.log, does it still happen?

Comment: @Barmar yes it does - I'm working in the Trigger.io framework and forgeLog simply outputs it to their web console debugger.

Answer (score 0):

yap i have also checked on many of browser but getting everything working fine its not giving any problem manually

what i think you are directly setting parser value in `JSON.stringify` some times it happens with **js**

try one thing intialize it in some object and pass that object in  `JSON.stringify` may it work

Answer (score 0):

Héctor from Parse was able to explain it to me:

> This is because createdAt, objectId, updatedAt, are not attributes.
>   They are properties of the object itself, so they are not being picked
>   up by the JSON serializer.